# How do I add Eclipse Indigo to the launcher?

Tags: unity, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pin eclipse indigo to Ubuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-indigo-to-ubuntu-11-10)

I know how to download Eclipse, and I figured I would put it in /opt, but how can I get it in the launcher?  I suppose I will need to uninstall the old Eclipse, but will the new Eclipse installation show up in the launcher, etc.?