# Ubuntu 11.10 Launcher Missing Icon

Tags: launcher

I download Eclipse, uncompressed it in my home folder, launched the application, and selected to keep the application in the launcher.  However, the eclipse icon is not being displayed.  I'm assuming because it is not technically an installed application.

How can I add an icon for an application in the launcher (ubuntu 11.10)?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/create-custom-unity-launcher/)
is how I created a launcher for Eclipse.

Had the same issue :) exactly for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way to create launcher. See:)

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-desktop-launchers-in-ubuntu-11-10oneiric.html

This is simple and you should be able to make a launcher for any application using it.

Comment: See below for instructions to automate

Answer (score 0):

This is how I automated creating launchers. This assumes you have already install 
gnome-panel.

1. Open a terminal
2. Either `mkdir /home/"your-user-name"/bin` or right click on your home folder in the file browser and make a folder named `bin`.
3. `source .profile` or logout and login
4. Open gedit and make a new file
5. Paste

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new
   ```

   into a new gedit file
6. Save it under a name with no space e.g `launcher-script` and make it executable by either typing `chmod a+x launcher-script` in the terminal, or right click>properties>Permissions and click the `execute` box.
7. in terminal: `sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new`

You should have the Create Launcher gui open.

8. Type: Application in Terminal. **This only applies this time.** Most of the time it will be "Application" after this.
9. You can name what you wish. **No spaces allowed**. I called mine "Create-Launcher"
10. In the command field put the path to the script from step 3

    ```
    /home/mike/bin/launcher-script
    ```

    but you must use your user name and your file name.
11. Click the spring(Launcher icon) to add an icon. I made one with Gimp but there are lots of icons you could use the ones that are very generic and already installed.
12. Once you're finished click OK. Now you can navigate your file browser down to `/usr/share/applications` and you will find your new launcher. Simply drag it to your launcher bar and you are ready to go. This process puts your launchers in a place where all users can access them. All of the instructions I have found puts thing on the desktop which might be fine for some but not for me. I hope you find this helpful.

Afterthought, every time you create a new launcher you will have to enter your  `sudo` password. This is necessary to make the new launcher accessible to all users. It will belong to root and the group will be root this way. That is the way the rest of the system comes configured. If you `cd` to `/usr/share/applications`, type `ls -l` and verify for yourself.