# Application isn't showing up in launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)

So I downloaded eclipse earlier today so I can start to learn the Android SDK. I typically write java programs with vim from the command line but I was having trouble making the sdk work from the command line. Anyways Eclipse was begin weird so I uninstalled it with Synaptic, then I reinstalled. Now it seems to be working fine except I can't get eclipse to show up in the launcher... Is there anything I may be missing that would make the launcher show up?