# Why Dash cant see new installed program?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)

I installed Eclipse IDE on my Ubuntu 11.10:

1) To install Eclipse need to download eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz from Download page

2) Untar downloaded archive tar zxvf eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz

3) Move to ~/ mv eclipse ~/eclipse.

After this I opened Dash Window and in input field writed Eclipse, but - Dash found nothing...

Why?

Maybe, I must add eclipse in some Dash programs list or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tar package from Eclipse does not include creating a launcher, you have just extracted the package, there was no installation.

You need to create a launcher and add it to dash for it to be available.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher) already has a explanation on how to do it, you just need to modify the path to the files (executable and icon) but the steps are the same.