# How to get my custom .desktop file into the unity launcher?

Tags: shortcuts, icons, games, lua

I've created a .desktop file like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Game;
Name=Mari0
Exec=love-unstable /opt/Mari0/mari0_1.0.love
Icon=/opt/Mari0/icon.gif
Type=Application
```

And what i want is to get it in the unity launcher under the games category

*I first asked how to create a shortcut file and how to get it into the launcher, but  now i've created a .desktop file myself. and i'm looking for how to get it into the launcher*

Comment: you might find this useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer i was looking for :D
http://askubuntu.com/a/53061/34385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to write bash file for example
just create a file and write this in

```
#!/bin/bash

cd dir_name; #the dir name to go

love-unstable mari0_1.0.love; #run the soft
```

then write in terminal `chmod +x name_what_you_place`
then you can just create a shortcut of that file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just associate .love files with the program love-unstable?  Then you could double click on the mari0_1.0.love file and it would run the program.