# How to add third-party app to Unity launcher and dash?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)

I've just downloaded an executable file from the Internet (an app) and would like to dock it in the Unity sidebar, but I can't just drag it over. In other apps I installed (aside from the Ubuntu Software Centre), their installer asked to register the app with the system, thus allowing me to properly use them with Unity and dock them.

How can I manually register my app with the system? I don't want to just dock the app, I'd like for it to also show up in searches, just like a normal USC-installed app behaves. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: you are I'm sure well aware, installing stuff from the internet should be done cautiously.  Perhaps can you clarify, what this file is and what instructions you have used to install it.

Comment: It's Eclipse IDE, it comes in a compressed file and right now the easiest way I can run it is directly double-clicking the executable. I'd like it to behave like the Eclipse in the USC (I can't use the Eclipse uploaded in the USC because it won't work for me).

Answer (score 1):

For it to be integrated in search, etc. the easiest way is to install alacarte. You can install it either from the Software Center, or with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Alacarte is the old menu editor used in earlier versions of Ubuntu. After it is installed, fire up alacarte, and make a menu item under the appropriate application menu (Programming for this example). It will now show up in your dash and you can pin it to your launcher like any other program.