# Eclipse launcher doesn't work in Xubuntu

Tags: launcher, eclipse, executable

I installed 12.04 xubuntu and latest eclipse. Java is also installed. path is set correctly. but there are two things strange to me.

1. when I double click the eclipse executable, it says cannot find java;
2. create a launcher on the desktop, it says the same thing as above;**

open a terminal, type `eclipse`, it will start eclipse without any error. type `java` in terminal also shows java is installed and available to the system.

Comment: Did you install eclipse from the standard repository or standalone (downloading from it's site)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to use update-alternatives to get the links to default locations in order.  Your edits to .bashrc aren't applied unless you run in a terminal.

Alternately, you could make a bash script to run your bashrc and then eclipse and use that as your launcher target.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question is duplicated and the following link can help:

[How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)