# Creating Physical Button for Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)

Running 12.04 and I downloaded Eclipse Juno from Eclipse, installed in Programs directory which I had created. How do I create a physical button so it can reside on the left menu, and show up in Dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file in your editor and save in this location:

```bsh
/usr/share/applications/
```

You can name it whatever you want, but it must have the `.destop` extension, for example:

```bsh
/usr/share/applications/juno.desktop
```

Inside the file, paste this code:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry] 
Name=Eclipse Juno 
Comment=Eclipse Juno application
Exec=path/to/the/file
Icon=/Path/to/your/icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Keywords=eclipse;java;juno;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look on this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/fballem/Software%2012.04
you will find instructions for installing a number of pieces of software, including Eclipse.

Hope this helps,