# Eclipse with log error

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

```
root@deepak:~# eclipse

** (eclipse:28003): WARNING **: The connection is closed
find: `/root/.eclipse': No such file or directory
find: `/root/.eclipse': No such file or directory
W: Cannot inject update-sites, cannot find the correct config.

** (eclipse:28002): WARNING **: The connection is closed

** (Eclipse:28002): WARNING **: The connection is closed

** (Eclipse:28002): WARNING **: The connection is closed

** (Eclipse:28002): WARNING **: The connection is closed

** (Eclipse:28002): WARNING **: The connection is closed

** (Eclipse:28002): WARNING **: The connection is closed
```

similar when i try to logged in User then

/home/deepak/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1350065308917.log.

log message

```
!SESSION 2013-10-12 23:38:28.737 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-10-12 23:38:31.851
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
        no swt-gtk in java.library.path
        Can't load library: /home/deepak/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk-3740.so
        Can't load library: /home/deepak/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk.so

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some java libraries from the error messages. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java
```

I think those are the correct packages, but when you see error messages like `Unsatistified dependency` this means you are missing something the program needs to work. So you need to find the package that has that dependency and add it to your computer.