# How can I get sikuli-ide to work?

Tags: java

I installed sikuli-ide with

```
sudo apt-get install sikuli-ide
```

Everything was fine until I tried to start it from the terminal. I typed

```
sikuli-ide
```

But the only response I got was

```
[info] locale: en_US
```

The application was not started, furthermore there is no desktop file and sikuli-ide does not show up in Dash Home.

I guess there is something wrong with the package. I run Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

I tried to install it (Sikuli-X-1.0rc3 (r905)-linux-x86_64.zip) from their [page](http://www.sikuli.org/download.html), now the IDE starts, but when I try to execute a simple script I get the following error:

```
[error] Stopped
[error] An error occurs at line 1
[error] Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/home/ayckoster/opt/Sikuli-IDE/sikuli-script.jar/Lib/sikuli/__init__.py", line 3, in 
File "/home/ayckoster/opt/Sikuli-IDE/sikuli-script.jar/Lib/sikuli/Sikuli.py", line 22, in 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ayckoster/opt/Sikuli-IDE/libs/libVisionProxy.so: libml.so.2.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1935)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1860)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
at com.wapmx.nativeutils.jniloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:44)
at org.sikuli.script.Finder.(Finder.java:33)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.

Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.python.core.Py.loadAndInitClass(Py.java:895)
at org.python.core.Py.findClassInternal(Py.java:830)
at org.python.core.Py.findClassEx(Py.java:881)
at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.findClass(SysPackageManager.java:133)
at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.findClass(PackageManager.java:28)
at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.findClass(SysPackageManager.java:122)
at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.__findattr_ex__(PyJavaPackage.java:137)
at org.python.core.PyObject.__findattr__(PyObject.java:863)
at org.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:849)
at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:884)
at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)
at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:357)
at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1173)
at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:978)
at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:954)
at sikuli.Sikuli$py.f$0(/home/ayckoster/opt/Sikuli-IDE/siku

li-script.jar/Lib/sikuli/Sikuli.py:211)
at sikuli.Sikuli$py.call_function(/home/ayckoster/opt/Sikuli-IDE/sikuli-script.jar/Lib/sikuli/Sikuli.py)
at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:386)
at org.python.core.util.importer.importer_load_module(importer.java:109)
at org.python.modules.zipimport.zipimporter.zipimporter_load_module(zipimporter.java:161)
at org.python.modules.zipimport.zipimporter$zipimporter_load_module_exposer.__call__(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.__call__(PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.java:47)
at org.python.core.imp.loadFromLoader(imp.java:513)
at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:467)
at org.python.core.PyModule.impAttr(PyModule.java:100)
at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:715)
at org.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:824)
at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:884)
at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)


at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:357)
at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1173)
at org.python.core.imp.importAll(imp.java:998)
at sikuli$py.f$0(/home/ayckoster/opt/Sikuli-IDE/sikuli-script.jar/Lib/sikuli/__init__.py:3)
at sikuli$py.call_function(/home/ayckoster/opt/Sikuli-IDE/sikuli-script.jar/Lib/sikuli/__init__.py)
at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:386)
at org.python.core.util.importer.importer_load_module(importer.java:109)
at org.python.modules.zipimport.zipimporter.zipimporter_load_module(zipimporter.java:161)
at org.python.modules.zipimport.zipimporter$zipimporter_load_module_exposer.__call__(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.__call__(PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.java:47)
at org.python.core.imp.loadFromLoader(imp.java:513)
at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:467)
at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:713)
at or

g.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:824)
at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:884)
at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)
at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:357)
at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1173)
at org.python.core.imp.importAll(imp.java:998)
at org.python.pycode._pyx2.f$0(:1)
at org.python.pycode._pyx2.call_function()
at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1261)
at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1305)
at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:206)
at org.sikuli.script.ScriptRunner.runPython(ScriptRunner.java:61)
at org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE$ButtonRun.runPython(SikuliIDE.java:1572)
at org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE$ButtonRun$1.run(SikuliIDE.java:1677)

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ayckoster/opt/Sikuli-IDE/libs/libVisionProxy.so: libml.so.2.1: 

cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I try to use the click() method from the gui it fails. So I created my own click method and it look like this:

[image]

This cannot be executed and produces the error above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens to me too. It seems the package has some problem (maybe a missing dependency?).

What I recommend (worked for me) is that you uninstall it and use the version provided in their [webpage](http://www.sikuli.org/download.html). You just need to extract the folder and place it where you want. Inside you find a `sikuli-ide.sh` file which you can use to start it.

After that you can create a launcher to it if you want (example for Eclipse [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/80016/33871)).

#### Edit

I forgot to mention: as stated in their webpage Sikuli requires OpenCV 2.1. Unfortunately 12. 10 only provides OpenCV 2.3/2.4 and it didn't worked for me.
The easiest way to solve this was installing OpenCV 2.1 packages from Oneiric. You will need 3 packages:

- [libhighgui2. 1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/oneiric/amd64/libhighgui2.1/download) ([x86](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/oneiric/i386/libhighgui2.1/download))
- [libcvaux-2. 1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/oneiric/amd64/libcvaux2.1/download) ([x86](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/oneiric/i386/libcvaux2.1/download))
- [libcv2. 1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/oneiric/amd64/libcv2.1/download) ([x86](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/oneiric/i386/libcv2.1/download))

After you download them (choose a mirror on each link) install them in that order (libhighgui first) using Software Center (just double click each package).

Another way can be achieved by downloading OpenCV 2.1 and build it manually. I haven't done it ever, so I can't tell you how hard it is.

Comment: Does it currently work for you? Can you actually execute scripts that click around on 12.10?

Comment: @ayckoster sorry, i forgot to mention some steps. Updated.

Comment: I had to also install libjpeg62 as a dependency from 12.10 repository. Otherwise I can actually use sikuli-ide. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## Sikuli-IDE on Ubuntu 12.10

(Done from a fresh install, 1/3/2013 6:00pm EST)

*Requirements for Sikuli: SUN java 6, openCV 2.1*

## Oracle Sun Java 6:

1. add the packages sources.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   ```
2. install oracle-java6.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
   ```

## OpenCV 2.1:

1. Above installs sun java 6, required for sikuli

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Then add the below line to the above file

   ```
   deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ oneiric main universe
   ```

   *Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and hit <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.*
3. update the packages repository and install it.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libhighgui2.1 libcvaux2.1 libcv2.1
   ```

## Now for sikuli:

Download from here http://www.sikuli.org/download.html. Extract to home, cd into the folder and run `sikuli.ide.sh`, Always run it from that .sh script, everything works fine.

Everything seems to work, including clicking, OCR, python syntax, screenshots...etc

Comment: I had to do "sudo apt-get update" before "sudo apt-get install ...". Worked perfectly otherwise, thx

Answer (score 0):

## OpenCV 2.1 on Ubuntu 12.10

- add the Ubuntu 11.10 source.

> $ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
>
> ......
>
> deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ oneiric main universe

- update repo.

> $ sudo apt-get update

- install the OpenCV 2.1 lib.

> $ sudo apt-get install libhighgui2.1 libcvaux2.1 libcv2.1

I has patched it.

Answer (score 0):

## sikuli-ide on Debian 7.0 amd64

install.

```
$ sudo aptitude install sikuli-ide
```

Info.

```
$ aptitude show sikuli-ide
Package: sikuli-ide                      
New: yes
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 1.0~x~rc3.tesseract3-dfsg1-5
Priority: extra
Section: java
Maintainer: Debian Java maintainers <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 553 k
Depends: libcommons-cli-java, libjson-simple-java, libjxgrabkey-java, libmac-widgets-java, default-jre (>= 1:1.6) | java6-runtime, libsikuli-script-java,
         junit, libswingx-java, libswing-layout-java
Description: IDE to develop sikuli scripts and use them a junit test cases
......
```

Run.

```
$ sikuli-ide 
[info] locale: en_US
```