# Create shortcut for "MyEclipse"

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

I use Ubuntu 14.04. I installed [Myeclipse 2015](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/) and it work normal, but every time I launch it, I need to go to terminal and launch th einstallation file.

I installed Myeclipse in `/opt/MyEclipse`.

I tried to create it like Eclipse, but it doesn't work: 
[How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)

How to create the shortcut?

Comment: Show us the contents of the desktop file.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0m54Vah.png?1

Comment: No the content of e.g. `myeclipse.desktop`. :)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/H6iuoa3.png?1

Comment: That looks good. Is `/opt/eclipse/myeclipse` executable (`ls -l /opt/eclipse/myeclipse`)?

Comment: i install it in /opt/MyEclipse and the result of ls -l /opt/Myeclipse is 
http://i.imgur.com/kdx52y4.png?1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I have a short answer.

The command to start `MyEclipse` in a terminal is

```
/opt/MyEclipse/myeclipse
```

or in your desktop file

```
Exec=/opt/MyEclipse/myeclipse
```

---

**The complete desktop file**

Open or create the desktop file

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/opt_eclipse.desktop
```

and add the lines below

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyEclipse 
Comment=MyEclipse Integrated Development Environment 
Icon=/opt/MyEclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/opt/MyEclipse/myeclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;     
StartupWMClass=MyEclipse
```

Comment: Extremely short!

Comment: @Fabby improved :)