# Install application ubuntu14.04 lts

Tags: icons

I am a beginner , just want to ask why ubuntu doesn't create by default a run icon in my /usr/share/application.
i installed netbeans and a run icon was created in the application directory but when i installed xampp that doesn't work for displaying the run icon.
what i must do to create the default run icon without using a script for run .

Comment: XAMPP is a 3rd party application and not maintained by Ubuntu/Canonical. If they do not provide a launcher icon for something you can run you need to make it yourself. By the way: what is suppose to run when you click a xampp run icon? ! Since xampp should already be running when you start your system. Besided that: do realize xampp is a webserver and those tend to focus on server installs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is available in left vertical sidebar. You need to search for it and then pull it on the left vertical sidebar.
Then it will be available for some of them like Eclipse you can create it following this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)