# How to create Eclipse 2019-20 launcher on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: launcher, icons, eclipse

I am Trying to Create Eclipse jee-2019-20 launcher on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

using below command and save it as eclipse.desktop  on Download Folder

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/home/feel/eclipse/jee-2019-122/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/feel/eclipse/jee-2019-122/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=IDE
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

Comment: Works for me if I change the `Icon` and `Exec` paths.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an extra 2 in `jee-2019-122` for both `Exec` and `Icon` file paths. Maybe it should be `jee-2019-12`, unless the extra 2 is intentional.

Otherwise your desktop entry file seems correct and similar to mine. I just solved this similar issue on Pop!_OS 19.10.

Place the eclipse.desktop file you created into `~/.local/share/applications`. I also right clicked eclipse.desktop and went into `Properties`, then the `Permissions` tab, and checked the box for `Allow executing file as program`.

This old answer helped me [How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher)